# How to make a block non-cacheble in default.xml

Tags: magento2, cache

I want to add a block in header which will not be cached. The block needs to be added to default.xml. I can't set `cacheble="false"`to the block as it will make all pages non-cacheble ( [Reference](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/public-content/#caching) ). What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the block, but you can not work with visitor-specific elements - such as a customer's name or cart contents - in pure PHP.

Instead, you need to handle the data using Knockout.js

Here is the relevant documentation on this: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/

Comment: I have an input field on the block where user can add their zipcode, and after pressing the submit, I am adding the zipcode in a cookie using Js. I know that to update private content, you need to have a sections.xml where you put a controller path , upon hitting which the content refreshes. In my case, I am seeing the old zipcode even after I have set the cookie, and refreshed the page. It updated only after I clean the cache. Should I add `cms/index/index` in sections ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but I guess that you're reading the cookie with PHP? That's wrong; you must read it with JS. If that doesn't work, check if you _controller path_ is correct in sections.xml, and maybe try to update all sections instead of only your own; but again, hard to say without the code.

Comment: @AniruddhaRay if you're setting the cookie via JS, maybe it's wise to populate the field via using JS as well. I mean, keep the field empty by default and once the page is loaded, populate the value via JS.